# SQL: Sequence of AND/OR statements

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

What I'm trying to solve for: Where statement where query checks if Condition 1 is A OR B WHILE Condition 2 is NOT C, D in the same row.

```
WHERE Condition1 LIKE 'A' OR Condition1 LIKE 'B' AND "Condition2" <> 'C' AND "Condition2" <> 'D'
```

Is this close?  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track, but you're missing the fact that `AND` has a higher priority than `OR`.
The most elegant way I could think of to express your desired condition is the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM   some_table
WHERE  c1 IN ('A', 'B') AND c2 NOT IN ('C', 'D');
```

Comment: @MartinSmith Indeed - this was supposed to be `c2` - stupid typo. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: I removed my upvote when you added "Your condition will do the trick" which is not quite correct because there is no grouping.

Comment: @Asaph - Indeed, you are correct - I missed that in the OP. Nice catch! I rephrased my answer to fix this error.

Answer (score 2):

You should group your sub-expressions in parenthesis, otherwise you're risking ambiguity around what is grouped together:

```
WHERE
    (Condition1 = 'A' OR Condition1 = 'B')
    AND
    (Condition2 <> 'C' AND Condition2 <> 'D')
```

In this case you don't *really* need the parenthesis around the second part there, but you should **never** combine both `AND` and `OR` in the same sub-expression.

A likely problem with your original construct is that the expressions can be grouped like this:

```
WHERE
    Condition1 = 'A'
    OR
    (Condition1 = 'B' AND Condition2 <> 'C' AND Condition2 <> 'D')
```

Comment: Not only *can* the expressions be grouped as you demonstrate at the end of your answer, but since `AND` binds with higher precedence than `OR` that is exactly how the expression *will* be treated should explicit parentheses be absent.

Comment: I have never bothered to learn the distinct precedences between such things since I know that I have 2 problems, 1) I can't easily read the expression and know how it works out, and 2) some languages have it the other way (I forget which though). As such, I've learned to just add the required parenthesis to begin with, problem solved (permanently).

Comment: No languages have it the other way. No useable ones, anyway. That would literally defy logic.

Comment: Actually, surprise: some languages such as APL and Smalltalk have no operator precedence. Expressions are evaluated from right to left and left to right, respectively -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages . We're always learning new things here on StackOverflow.